# _itoa_s kills C++ optimizing compiler all time, why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, itoa

I have a code on which the optimizing compiler always fails, with each launch.

```
char* GetWinSockVersion()
{
    char *tmpData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(wsaData.wVersion));
    _itoa_s<wsaData.wVersion>(wsaData.wVersion, tmpData, 10);
    return tmpData;
}
```

It does fail with the `_itoa_s`. I'm interested, why does it fail all times?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the compiler fails? Does it give a compiler error, does it crash, does it produce incorrect code?

Comment: @Grizzly it crashes with execution fail ( compilers fails at execution not my program )

Comment: @OlegOrlov Please add the message you're getting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the functions being used, but it does look like you're trying to convert into a buffer which is too small.  If the first argument to `_itoa_s` is an integer, then you're only allocating `sizeof int` bytes (typically 4), but you're telling `_itoa_s` that there are 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using the function properly.

[`_itoa_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) requires 4 arguments.

This function is meant to be used with `c`, for `c++` you have stream.

Your code should be more like ( assuming *wsaData.wVersion* is a number )

```
char *tmpData = (char*)malloc(sizeof( char ) * 80 );
_itoa_s(wsaData.wVersion , tmpData , 80 , 10);

//_itoa_s(number to convert , target string, size of target string, number base);
```